# StackTrace in release flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, stack-trace, flash

I have problem with getting stacktrace of errors.
When i use error.getStackTrace() in debug player it works fine.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ СЃРѕР·РґР°С‚СЊ СЃРІРѕР№СЃС‚РІРѕ asdad РІ starling.display.Stage. at app.views::MachineHeader/onSoundButtonTriggered() 
 [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../src/app/views/MachineHeader.as:111] at starling.events::EventDispatcher/invokeEvent()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as:141] at starling.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as:112] at starling.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventWith()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as:190] at org.feathers.controls::Button/button_touchHandler()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/org/feathers/controls/Button.as:3052] at starling.events::EventDispatcher/invokeEvent()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as:141] at starling.events::TouchEvent/dispatch()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/starling/events/TouchEvent.as:174] at starling.events::Touch/dispatchEvent()
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace/src/starling/events/Touch.as:231]
```

But on release player stackTrace looks like:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056
```

Code:

```
this.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onGlobalErrorsHandler);

private function onGlobalErrorsHandler(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void {
    if (_errorList[e.errorID]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    trace(e.error.getStackTrace());
    var data:Object = {};
    data["login"] = AMFService.instance.login;
    data["error_type"] = String(e.error.errorID);
    data["stacktrace"] = e.error.getStackTrace();
    AMFService.instance.sendError("statistics.error_send", data);

    _errorList[e.errorID] = e.error;

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Debug player: Linux 11.2
Release player: PepperFlash 11.9

What i'm doing wrong? How can i get stacktrace on release player?

Than you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable stacktraces in release player(11.5+), you have to compile your swf with swf-version=18

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html

Answer (score 2):

According to Adobe's API Reference for [Error.getStackTrace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#getStackTrace%28%29) ...

> *"For Flash Player 11.4 and earlier and AIR 3.4 and earlier, stack
>   traces are only available when code is running in the debugger version
>   of Flash Player or the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL). In non-debugger
>   versions of those runtimes, calling this method returns null."*

Sorry, but there's just no way around it. :(